# How to parse 'nested' json files and import into a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I was triyng to json normalize methods. It give me this solution.

```
json = {"vehicle_type":"Car","car_info":{"count":3,"infos":[{"car":"BMW","name":"5","description":"","production_time":"2017-07-16","tags":["car","BMW","sedan"],"references":[],"country":["germany"],"fuel_type":["electrical"],"color":"black","price":null,"technic":{"0-100":"-","horsepower":"165Nm"},"mileage":{"mile":14004}}]}}

df = json_normalize(json)
```

[This is my pandas.dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0NEK.png)

When i was trying to parse my nested json, there are still more dictionaries in some columns.
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FameB.png) with that code

```
df_car = pd.DataFrame()
empty_list = pd.DataFrame()
empty_list = [{}]


for i in range(len(df1)):
    if df1["car_info.infos"][i] == [{}]:
        df_car = df_car.append(empty_list,ignore_index = True)        
    else:
        car_info = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df1["car_info.infos"][i][0],orient='index'))
        car_info=car_info.transpose()
        df_car = df_car.append(car_info,ignore_index=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df1,df_car], axis = 1)
df2 = df2.drop(columns={"car_info.infos"})
```

i need code without column name to parse nested json until the all dicts are not exist. I have multiple json files. How can ı automatize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) with the parameters `record_path=` and `meta=`, as follows:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json, record_path=['car_info', 'infos'], meta=['vehicle_type', ['car_info', 'count']])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   car name description production_time               tags references    country     fuel_type  color  price technic.0-100 technic.horsepower  mileage.mile vehicle_type car_info.count
0  BMW    5                  2017-07-16  [car, BMW, sedan]         []  [germany]  [electrical]  black    NaN             -              165Nm         14004          Car              3
```

Comment: I'm very appreciative of  your answer. I will use that, ı have one more question. How can i use these methods while automatized it?

Comment: @AtakanAydınbaş  You can automate it if your json files are in similar structure. But if they are different and the record paths are different, I doubt whether there is any other way to automate it.